# Blackberry get JSON from web server URL

Tags: java, json, eclipse, blackberry

I have JSON code like this:

```
[{ "idShipping":"1328448569",
   "shippingDesti":"nusa tenggara barat",
   "shippingCosts":"21000"
 },
 { "idShipping":"1328448543",
   "shippingDesti":"nusa tenggara timur",
   "shippingCosts":"76000"
 }]
```

I followed a tutorial from this link: [BlackBerry read json string from an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668674/blackberry-read-json-string-from-an-url). I changed

```
private static final String NAME = "name";
```

from DataParser.java into

```
private static final String NAME = "idShipping";
```

but when i run it on a simulator, it showed a popup screen that said that it failed to parse data from MyScreen.java. It means I can get the JSON string, but I can't parse it.

How do I fix it?

Comment: your json is an JSON Array not a JSON  string

Comment: How to fix it anyway?

Comment: Please supply the code in question, rather than a link that points to another link... I got tired or looking for the code. Please try to step through the code, and point out where it breaks - I find that is a very useful way to debug JSON parsers. Looking forward to reading more details from you.....

Answer (score 0):

For the JSON you've shown, you would parse the `idShipping` values something like this:

```
  //String response = "[{\"idShipping\":\"1328448569\",\"shippingDesti\":\"nusa tenggara barat\",\"shippingCosts\":\"21000\"},{\"idShipping\":\"1328448543\",\"shippingDesti\":\"nusa tenggara timur\",\"shippingCosts\":\"76000\"}]";
  try {
     JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray(response);
     for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject nextObject = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
        if (nextObject.has("idShipping")) {
           String value = nextObject.getString("idShipping");
           System.out.println("next id is " + value);
        }
     }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
     // TODO: handle parsing error here
  }
```

The key, as Signare said, was parsing a `JSONArray`, and then getting a string value out of that.

Comment: Thx for your reply, but i still confuse. I got my JSON String from my server, and I should change the response like response that you remaked or just try the try catch part?

Comment: @Vely, You can get the JSON string from wherever you like.  Whatever you get back from the server would be the variable `response` in the code I show above.  I had to put something in to demonstrate how to parse your string, and test it myself.